# Lazy loading of footer in react

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I am building currently Single-Page Application in React its relatively long website (footerComponent is not visible on screen after loading) and I am wondering if there is a reason then to use React.lazy()&Suspense in this case? I  haven't used React.lazy() in the past and I am still not sure enough when to use it. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Good point. but remember to place a condition to render it (such as [router in react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting)). otherwise, it still loads at the start like normal.

Comment: I am not sure if I get it correctly. Do I have to implement react-router-dom then and wrap  something in <Route> ? Cannot I just import Footer with .lazy() and then wrap it with <Suspense>?

Comment: No you don't need `react-router-dom`. if you only want to lazy load a footer. just make a condition that describes when to load it such as `{isLoadFooter ? <footer_component_which_use_lazy_suspense/>: ''}`. The complicated thing is that how you know when to set the state `isLoadFooter`.

Comment: Because of complex task you have to do to optimize a small footer, I don't think it's not worth your time. Just use lazy loading for bigger component such as a entire route. I just learned it too, so correct me if I'm wrong.